# Trying to update header sizing on mobile, but CSS isn't responding. Am I missing something?

Tags: html, css

Trying to update CSS so that the headline adapts and becomes smaller when viewing mobile. Might be missing something or there's some other CSS that controls it but not sure where.

I've tried looking up various code, but testing it locally, still not getting desired result.

HTML

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-auto cta-headline">
        <h2><span class="cta-headline">SIGN UP!</span></h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cta-headline {
        color: $white;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-family: "Gilroy", "Helvetica", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        @media only screen and (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 959px) { 
          .cta-headline { font-size: 10px;
          }
        }
    }
```

I'd like the text to just scale appropriately down when viewing mobile compared to desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Sass? Because CSS you shouldn't be nesting media queries inside the class. Just move the media query to its own line and it should work.

The min & max width is also redundant, it's much better to just remove the min and keep the max. If the width goes below 450px, create another media query where the max width is 450px

```
.cta-headline {
        color: $white;
        font-weight: 800;
        font-family: "Gilroy", "Helvetica", Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        margin-bottom: -15px;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) { 
        .cta-headline { font-size: 10px; }
    }
```